# Exclude a specific value from my SQL list

Tags: sql

I have created a SQL command that returns a comma-separated list which works fine.

Now I want to exclude a value from that list if it equals `MYVALUE2`.

Can anyone help me with that?

My code:

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT 
    @listStr = COALESCE (@listStr + ',', '') + Name + ' - ' + REPLACE(Description, ',', '')
FROM 
    admin.Jobs
WHERE 
    Customer = '**MYVALUE1**'
    AND Category = 'SERIEN'
ORDER BY 
    Name

SELECT @listStr
```

My result:

```
SID0000130 - Die Serie vom goldenen Traum Staffel 1,SID0000140 - Serie vom Milchtraum,SID0000141 - Testserie
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: Always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using. Most DBMS can do the above with a single query and without the use of variables.